# How to click on an element through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to click an item in a product page to add to my cart something but I can't do it because I am getting many errors or nothing happens.
This is my code :

```
i = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='exclusive']")
i.click
```

and this is the webpage code:

```html
<p id="add_to_cart" class="buttons_bottom_block no-print">
  <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="exclusive">
    <span>Add to cart</span>
    </button>
</p>
```

sorry if I made mistake but I'm new! Thanks for your help.

Comment: `i.click()`. Correct this maybe your syntax is wrong

Comment: *I am getting many errors* which are? post add them to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click the item in the product page to add to cart you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.buttons_bottom_block.no-print>button.exclusive[name='Submit']>span").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='buttons_bottom_block no-print']/button[@class='exclusive']/span[text()='Add to cart']").click()
  ```